# How to hide geckodriver console window?

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, console, geckodriver

I'm running Selenium 3.141.0 with python 3.6.7 on windows 10

My script runs the Firefox driver in headless, however a console window from geckodriver still pops up.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\webdrivers\geckodriver.exe', log_path='C:\webdrivers\geckodriver.log', firefox_options=options)
driver.get('http://10.0.0.102/')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "body-home-tile-pgDevServ"))
)
button = driver.find_element_by_id('body-home-tile-pgDevServ')
button.click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "devserv-printQ-Inp"))
)
button = driver.find_element_by_id('devserv-printQ-Inp')
button.click()
```

Comment: I achieved this in c# by getting the handler and using the win32 api and hiding the windows
`IntPtr intPtr = Win32API.FindWindow("className", null);`
 `Win32API.ShowWindow(intPtr, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some messing around it seems like adding `options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')` fixes it (sometimes).

Running the script from vscode works, running the script with windows task scheduler works.
Running from powershell or cmd does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I hacked the ***selenium*** lib, change the code in,
\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py
line 72 and below,

the ***original codes*** as:

```
        try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file,
                                        stderr=self.log_file,
                                        stdin=PIPE)
```

and add two more lines, like this

```
        try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file,
                                        stderr=self.log_file,
                                        creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                                        stdin=PIPE)
```

It works for windows.

Comment: Tested on python 3.8xx and it does work. The location is a little different than you mentioned: {wherever python is installed}\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common

Answer (score 4):

I found a way, based on the solution by Anguo Zhao, to solve this without editing the selenium file itself, by monkey-patching it into the imported selenium module:

```py
import functools

from selenium import webdriver

flag = 0x08000000  # No-Window flag
# flag = 0x00000008  # Detached-Process flag, if first doesn't work
webdriver.common.service.subprocess.Popen = functools.partial(
    webdriver.common.service.subprocess.Popen, creationflags=flag)
```

If you think that this might be executed more than once:

```py
import functools
import subprocess

from selenium import webdriver

flag = 0x08000000  # No-Window flag
webdriver.common.service.subprocess.Popen = functools.partial(
    subprocess.Popen, creationflags=flag)
```

I couldn't find a place in the selenium module where it would use `creationflags` by itself, so that shouldn't break anything (as of now).

#### Natural Language Explanation:

With `functools.partial`, we create a "prepared" `Popen`-call that has the `creationflags`-argument already with it.
Then, we replace the original `Popen` that selenium tries to call with that prepared one.
Voilà, whenever something in `selenium.webdriver.common.service` tries to create a `Popen`-object, it will be the one that has been prepared with the creationflag.