# Is it possible to hide a console window from another program?

Tags: python, windows, process

I have a pythonscript that automates something in firefox so it needs geckodriver.exe to run simultaneously. The problem is that when geckodriver.exe launches, it brings up a console window which annoys me. Is it possible to remove that window or hide it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984953/how-to-hide-geckodriver-console-window

Answer (score 0):

If program is sub process of your script answer is yes. you can use `subprocess` and set some parameters to hide the window just like this code.

```
import subprocess
check_call=subprocess.check_call
STDOUT=subprocess.STDOUT

if hasattr(subprocess,'DEVNULL'):
    DEVNULL=subprocess.DEVNULL
    pass
else:
    DEVNULL= open(os.devnull, 'w')


   check_call(["geckodriver.exe"], shell=True, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
```

In this case, you can use the code for windows, linux and macOS.

Comment: Thanks I will try it but where do I have to Insert that code?

Comment: You don't need to use the shell or `DEVNULL`. Just pass `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.